# Как бы это написать правильнее...?

Tags: пунктуация

Ват Сисакет, Онг Теу Махавихан, Ингг Пенг, с традиционными лаосскими крышами, буддийская ступа Пха Тхатлуанг на окраине города, и, наконец, Тхат Дам. ("С традиционными лаосскими крышами - три первых перечисленных храма, а прочитал свою фразу, выглядит как будто это только к последнему из трех относится. Как и  при помощи каких знаков исправить?)

Answer (score 1):

*Ват Сисакет, Онг Теу Махавихан, Ингг Пенг, **все -**  с традиционными лаосскими крышами, буддийская ступа Пха Тхатлуанг на окраине города, и, наконец, Тхат Дам.*

Знаками тут ничего не поправишь.

Что касается идеи не обособлять "наконец", то я с ней не согласен. Здесь "наконец" вполне годится на роль вводного. 
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_436

Тут скорее будет сложно обосновать, что "наконец" = "в конце концов, в конечном итоге" и является членом предложения. Так что с Niemand'ом опять не согласен.
(+)
Насчет запятой перед И, так понравившейся Niemand'у. Все предложение можно рассматривать как ССП с тремя односоставными (назывными) составляющими. Распространенность первого из них даёт веские основания именно для такого подхода. А раз так, то и запятая перед "И" вполне уместна. Разумеется, я не утверждаю, что она нам стопроцентно нужна, поскольку можно трактовать и как пять однородные главные члены односоставного. Но я бы тоже запятую использовал.

Comment: Кстати, вы не заметили еще одну лишнюю запятую - перед И.

Comment: Нет, запятая там не лишняя.

Answer (score 0):

"... – все с традиционными лаосскими крышами, ..."

"...и наконец..." – без запятых.